# How to show current location marker in Ionic 2 with Ionic Native Geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, geolocation

Im using Ionic 2 and i want to make geolocation app. This is my code to show my current location marker with **Ionic Native Geolocation** :

```
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {
  // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
  let pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
    data.coords.latitude,
    data.coords.longitude
  );

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos
    // icon: 'assets/icon/marker2.png'
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
  map.setCenter(pos);

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('<b>Your Location</b>');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

when i run in browser, the marker are appears, but when i run in android device, the marker are not appears....
please what should i do?

sorry for bad english.

Comment: Do you have any log error when run on android?

Comment: no, the code just run well. thats make me confuse

Comment: try to reinstall the plugin

Comment: i already did it, but still not work

Comment: did you got your solution ??? .... plz share your solution